How to get states of containers?
I use this lib com.github.docker-java:docker-java:3.3.6
I have a problem, I just can’t find the methods that would be responsible for:

How much disk memory does the container occupy, and what is the maximum amount it can occupy?
Bandwidth speed of the container’s Internet connection.
And if possible, the quality of the Internet connection (preferably in Mbs) between my application and the docker itself

If you know please tell me

I'm not totally clear what you're asking on the last two points.  On native Linux, Docker uses kernel-internal networking setup so container-to-container and host-to-container networking should be quite fast; with Docker Desktop, entering and leaving the Linux VM will be slower, but it's not something that would be measurable on a per-container basis.

@DavidMaze, in Docker Desktop, I would like to know the stability of the Internet connection with the docker itself, but I also don’t know how I can get this, and I also don’t know how to find out the container size in the Java Docker API, maybe you know?
